# Comparison between pointer and integer in C on X86 vs ARM

Tags: c, gcc, arm

in my program I compare char against hexadecimal int and I get different results for
running in X86 PC and ARM handheld, compiled with arm-gcc or native gcc on n900, either way,
condition is true for PC and not passing on mobile.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      if (*argv[1] == 0xffffffcc)
          puts("ok");

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: What character are you actually trying to test for? Latin Capital Letter I With Grave or the start of a utf-8 sequence?

Comment: on both arches I'm doing: `./a.out $(printf "0xcc" | xxd -r)`

Comment: Where in this question do you compare a pointer and an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably more sensible to compare with an acutal character constant. Although integer promotions will still happen to both operands of `==`, at least they will happen in the same way and you will not be depending on the signedness of your `char` of the size of your `int` or `unsigned int`.

E.g.

```
if (*argv[1] == '\xcc')
```

I believe that it is common for ARM compilers to make `char` unsigned which means that when `'\xcc'` is promoted to an integer you get the value `0xcc`, not `0xffffffcc`.

Comment: @randomonkey: Why is that funny?

Comment: @randomonkey, Consider to accept some answer to your question. I had a look to your profile: it seems you always got an answer and you didn't accept any of them, just commented that it was ok.

Comment: @Zagorax, ah I just found out that I can "accept" quiestions, txs!

Answer (score 5):

On ARM systems, `char` type is usually unsigned by default while on x86 it is usually signed. The equality operator `==` performs integer promotions of both operands, so the difference of the  behavior when `*argv[1]` is considered as signed (sign extension is performed) or unsigned (no sign extension is performed).

With `gcc` note that you can change the default of type `char` with the options `-fsigned-char` and `-funsigned-char`.